# Finding the smalles value per key and building an array based on the key as an index

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some code to create a dictionary which has different values per keys, the values can be random and sometimes a key can be empty, my keys are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.  an example of a dictionary I could have:

```
{0: [361.7, 104.1, 1416.1, 759.0, 750.3, 615.0], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [1056.3, 136.2, 98.6], 5: [], 6: [], 7: []}
```

I want to however find the lowest value per key, then build an array using the key as an index,  the result would be:

```
ArrayOfData = [104.1,0,0,0,98.6,0,0,0]
```

Most examples I have seen imply finding the lowest value and grabbing the key, but in my case I want to have the lowest value per key.

Answer (score 4):

You can loop over your `dict.values` and get the `min` of each value list, unless it is empty then just fill it in as `0`

```
>>> [min(v, default=0.0) for v in d.values()]
[104.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 98.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Note that the dictionary order is not specified until 3.7 or later